# Invalid packet type error using php_mysql_xdevapi

Tags: php, mysql, nosql, document-store

I am trying to connect to mysql 8.0.15 using php_mysql_xdevapi but getting following errror.

> Notice: mysql_xdevapi\getSession(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught mysql_xdevapi\Exception: [2000][HY000] The server sent invalid packet type
>   I am using

- Windows 10

  - MySQL 8.0.15
  - PHP 7.3.0
  - PECL Extension MySQL X DevAPI for PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 2 days of searching, I make **php_mysql_xdevapi** work on windows using wampserver.

Steps to make **php_mysql_xdevapi** work on windows 10, using wamp.

1. Install Pecl extension **php_mysql_xdevapi**.
2. Add the extension into the ini  `extension=php_mysql_xdevapi`
3. Be default in wamp the **XPlugin** is disable enable it in my.ini

   `;Disabling X Plugin
    ;mysqlx=0`
4. use this to connect to mysql using php_mysql_xdevapi

   `$session = mysql_xdevapi\getSession('mysqlx://root:123@localhost:33060?connect-timeout=5000&ssl-mode=disabled');`

Now you can use this to further query in mysql document store.